# Why generator gives same output if not assigned to a variable

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I had created a function foo as following

```
function* foo(){
  var index = 0;
  while (index <= 2)
    yield index++;
}
```

when I call following function gives same output

```
console.log(foo().next()); //Object {value: 0, done: false}
console.log(foo().next()); //Object {value: 0, done: false}
console.log(foo().next()); //Object {value: 0, done: false}
```

but when I tried following gave output as excepted

```
var xx=foo();
console.log(xx.next()); //Object {value: 0, done: false}
console.log(xx.next()); //Object {value: 1, done: false}
console.log(xx.next()); //Object {value: 2, done: false}
console.log(xx.next()); //Object {value: undefined, done: true}
```

> I just wanna understand the reason behind it, why this happened

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generator functions return an Iterator when called. Calling the generator again returns a new iterator.

Here's an example of how this works:

```
function* countdown(start){
  while (start > 0)
    yield start--;
}

var countdown1 = countdown(10);
var countdown2 = countdown(20);
```

Now we have 2 "live" countdown iterators, the 1st will yield 10..1, the 2nd will yield 20..1. We can call `.next()` on each independent of the other and state is maintained correctly:

```
console.log(countdown1.next().value) // 10
console.log(countdown1.next().value) // 9
console.log(countdown1.next().value) // 8

console.log(countdown2.next().value) // 20
console.log(countdown2.next().value) // 19
console.log(countdown2.next().value) // 18

console.log(countdown1.next().value) // 7
console.log(countdown1.next().value) // 6
console.log(countdown1.next().value) // 5
```

An iterator doesn't have to be generated by a generator though... All it takes for an object to be an iterator is that it has a `next()` member function that returns an object with the signature `{value: x, done: trueOrFalse}`. To make good use of this pattern though, you need to attach it to an iterable. Iterable is an object that has a `[Symbol.iterator]` property that returns an iterator. For example:

```
function nonGeneratorCountdown() {
  return {
    next: arg => {
      if (this.count > 0) {
        return {value: this.count--, done: false};
      }
      return {done: true};
    }
  };
}
var iterable = {
  count: 3,
  [Symbol.iterator]: nonGeneratorCountdown
};

for(let i of iterable) {
  console.log(i); // 3, 2, 1
}
```

---

So... in your code:

```
console.log(foo().next());
```

Always returns a new iterator, calls `.next()` on it and logs the returned value.

```
var xx=foo();
console.log(xx.next());
console.log(xx.next());
```

On the other hand only uses a single iterator several times, and logs the iterated (and changing) results from it.

Comment: This is both true and the the correct answer - but it does very little to illustrate and explain the behavior to the OP. Please consider adding an example, explaining why it's useful or doing something similar of the sort.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - Better? :-)

Comment: Much, thanks. An example with an iterator that's not a generator would also be nice :)